# Wordpress template only showing most recent 5 posts

Tags: php, wordpress

All of my templates are using the following to display all posts from a given category:

```
<ul>
    <?php $posts = get_posts('category_name=jobs'); foreach($posts as $post) { ?>
    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" target="_parent"><?php the_title(); ?></a>   
        </li>
    <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

The above template code however isn't showing more than the 5 most recent posts from the "jobs" category. There are more than 5 to show, and they do have a "Published" status.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

get_posts has default values that you can edit

```
<?php $args = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => 5,
    'offset'           => 0,
    'category'         => '',
    'orderby'          => 'post_date',
    'order'            => 'DESC',
    'include'          => '',
    'exclude'          => '',
    'meta_key'         => '',
    'meta_value'       => '',
    'post_type'        => 'post',
    'post_mime_type'   => '',
    'post_parent'      => '',
    'post_status'      => 'publish',
    'suppress_filters' => true ); ?>
```

for more : http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts

hope it helps

Comment: I tried `<?php $posts = get_posts('category_name=jobs', 'numberposts=25'); foreach($posts as $post) { ?>` but not seeing a change.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your code to this:

```
$posts = get_posts ( array ( 'category_name' => 'jobs', 'posts_per_page' => -1));
```

Using `-1` will display all posts. You could change this to another positive integer to limit the posts you return.

Comment: Figured out that I just needed to add `&numberposts=300` to get_posts.

Answer (score 0):

`get_posts` and `get_pages` are kind of a mess, in my experience. Sometimes it helps to look at documentation for both [get_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts) and [get_pages](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages) to get a sense of what they both can do -- sometimes something's on the menu for posts but not pages -- but sometimes it'll actually work in both places.

In this case, the `get_pages` documentation tells us this about the `number` parameter:

> **number**
>   (*integer*) Sets the number of Pages to list. This causes the
>   SQL LIMIT value to be defined. Default to no LIMIT. This parameter was
>   added with Version 2.8.
>
> **Note:** get_posts() uses the parameter `numberposts` instead of `number`.

The only mention of `numberposts` on the `get_posts` documentation at the time of this writing is as follows:

> **Note:** 'numberposts' and 'posts_per_page' can be used interchangeably.

Go figure.

Anyway, there you have it -- `numberposts`.

So if you want 10 posts...:

`get_posts('category_name=jobs&numberposts=10')`